# django form: CheckboxSelectMultiple's id_for_label does not work

Tags: html, django, forms

I want to customize my label style, so I overwrite {{ form }} in my html template with a for loop through all choices. But I found I lost label 'for' attribute and 'id' of the input for each choice after using for loop.
**Old codes:**
html template:

```
{% block form %}
<button class="checker">Uncheck all</button>  <button class="allChecker">Check all</button>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

my form:

```
class RerunForm(forms.Form):
    items = ItemStatus(
        queryset=models.Container.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs=dict(checked='')),
        help_text="Select requirements/objectives that you want to rerun.",
    )

    def __init__(self, rerunqueryset, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RerunForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['items'].queryset = rerunqueryset

class ItemStatus(models.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        if '_' not in obj.name:
            return "{} ({})".format(obj.name.replace('-r1', '').replace('-s1', ''), obj.state)
        else:
            return ". . . {} ({})".format(obj.name.replace('-r1', ''), obj.state)
```

**New Codes**:
html template:

```
{% block form %}
<button class="checker">Uncheck all</button>  <button class="allChecker">Check all</button>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul id="id_items">
      {% for value, label, item in form.items.field.choices %}
      <li>
        <label for="{{ form.items.id }}">
          <input type="checkbox" value={{ value }} name="items" id="{{ form.items.auto_id }}">
          <span class="listItem-{{item.state}}">{{ label }}</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

new form:

```
class RerunForm(forms.Form):
    items = ItemStatus(
        queryset=models.Container.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs=dict(checked='')),
        help_text="Select requirements/objectives that you want to rerun.",
    )

    def __init__(self, rerunqueryset, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RerunForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['items'].queryset = rerunqueryset

class ItemStatus(models.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        if '_' not in obj.name:
            return "{} ({})".format(obj.name.replace('-r1', '').replace('-s1', ''), obj.state)
        else:
            return ". . . {} ({})".format(obj.name.replace('-r1', ''), obj.state)

    def _get_choices(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_choices'):
            return self._choices
        return CustomModelChoiceIterator(self)

    choices = property(_get_choices,
                       MultipleChoiceField._set_choices)


class CustomModelChoiceIterator(models.ModelChoiceIterator):
    def choice(self, obj):
        # return super(CustomModelChoiceIterator, self).choice(obj)
        return (self.field.prepare_value(obj),
                self.field.label_from_instance(obj),
                obj)
```

The old codes gave me `<label for='id_items_1'><input ... id='id_items_1>...` when I inspect, but the new codes only gave me `<label><input ...>` without for and id attributes.
I tried adding `<label for="{{ form.items.id_for_label }}>` in html, no luck.
then `<label for="{{ form.items.auto_it }}>` gave me `<label for="id_items">`, but not differentiate choice from one to another. Please help on how to add 'id_items_0', 'id_items_1',... as label 'for' and input 'id' to each of my choice in html?
I also attached what it looks like now with new codes.
[web-page and inspect results with new codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kzxJ.png)